# PDF viewer for joomla 1.7 (docstoc,..)

Tags: pdf, joomla, embed, joomla1.7

I'm looking for a pdf viewer for joomla 1.7, probably docstoc would work, but i cant find anywhere installation instructions.. lol I found out that you can copy paste the embed pdf link into joomla webpage just like this

joomla page: embed link

[X-press, May 2001 (PDF)](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/11960719/X-press-May-2001-(PDF))
var docstoc_docid="11960719";var docstoc_title="X-press, May 2001 (PDF)";var docstoc_urltitle="X-press, May 2001 (PDF)";

but this ingenious solution doesn't work
because joomla doesn't recognise the link...
any ideas how to fix that??

Comment: Ok i figured out that you need to copy paste the code into <HTML></HTML> code page, but for some reason after saving only link like above stays the whole pdf dissapears..

Comment: still the docstoc dissapears just the link stays...

Comment: so far figured out that joomla deletes, Yes it deletes some html code, and in order not to delete the code we have to assign some mysterious right to our super admin user 0_0 ... investigating further...

Comment: It's not just Joomla, it's most online WYSIWYG editors. They strip out any code that is not explicitly allowed in order to keep users from entering code that could be used to compromise the site. It's a security thing.

In order to accomplish what you want without compromising security you will need to create a plugin that inserts the necessary code anywhere you put in a placeholder for a link.

Comment: @Brent Friar hmm a lot of text dude, but still the solution is : article->options->text filtering-> filtering off(for your usr) thats it 5 words, problem solved :D

Comment: Learn something new every day! I didn't realize that they had included that option in 1.7. I would recommend not turning off the filtering completely though. You should use the whitelist with just the code you want to allow to minimize the security risk.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a plugin like: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/print-a-pdf/14117